# CSS animation stuck while js is busy

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a css animation and I have js code that doing something, let say loop over i:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)  {
 console.log(i);
}
```

This code hold my animation from running.
Is there a solution for that? Without using gif

html + css code

```
<div class="progress">
  <span></span>
</div>

.progress {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  > span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    &:after, >span {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
      background-image: linear-gradient(
        -45deg,
        rgba(#fff, .2) 25%,
        transparent 25%,
        transparent 50%,
        rgba(#fff, .2) 50%,
        rgba(#fff, .2) 75%,
        transparent 75%,
        transparent
      );
      z-index: 1;
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-animation: move 4s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: move 4s linear infinite;
        animation: move 4s linear infinite;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
}
```

[codepen - css animation](http://codepen.io/rans/pen/BzkREN)

Comment: why you need to use `console.log(i);`?

Comment: animation runs fine didn't see any pause or late start

Comment: If your JS takes a long time to execute you should consider splitting it up into smaller bits to avoid making your page unresponsive to user interaction.

Comment: @currarpickt - the `console.log(i);` - is just for the demonstration

Comment: @gcampbell - I can't break my code. It's used for the loading and the first calcultions of my application

Comment: @ran Splitting it up won't break it, it just means giving the browser breathing room to render the page.

Comment: @ran Did I sufficiently answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. Or at least not without reformatting your code. The reason the animation is getting stuck is because rendering the page is like any other function. If you hog the JS stack with your loop, there'll never be a time for the browser to re-render your screen thus rendering your animation.

**Potential Solution:**

You could use setInterval instead of a loop with a time of 0. What this does is pushes each function into a callback queue and it's executed every time the stack is clear. This allows time for the animation to render. You'd want something like this:

```
var counter = 0;

var inter = setInterval(function(){
 if(++counter >= 1000){
  return clearInterval(inter);
 }
 console.log(counter);
},0);
```

**Web Workers Solution**

You could also try using web workers. The Web Workers API allows you to run JS processes on a seperate thread. This would require you to store the JS in an external script.

Comment: Also see the experimental `requestIdleCallback`.

Comment: @gcampbell That's a good one, I've never heard of it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update 2021 - use async functions or Promises  to free up the browser for css animations

```
async function busyWork(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)  {
          console.log(i);
        }
}
```

or a Promise

```
new Promise(resolve=>{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)  {
      console.log(i);
    }
  resolve()
})
```